# Getting an error while starting the Jboss Server in AWS Cloud

Tags: jboss, wildfly

I'm facing this issue :

```
ERROR [AbstractKernelController] Error installing to Create: name=stdio-classloader:0.0.0$MODULE state=Configured: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to mount root "/opt/shared/web/jboss/jboss-6.1.0.Final/lib/jboss-stdio.jar"
    at org.jboss.classloading.spi.vfs.dependency.VFSClassLoaderPolicyModule.create(VFSClassLoaderPolicyModule.java:275) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.7.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [:1.7.0_261]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [:1.7.0_261]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:607) [:1.7.0_261]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:60) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.reflect.plugins.introspection.ReflectMethodInfoImpl.invoke(ReflectMethodInfoImpl.java:168) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.joinpoint.plugins.BasicMethodJoinPoint.dispatch(BasicMethodJoinPoint.java:66) [jboss-reflect.jar:2.2.1.SP1]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction$JoinpointDispatchWrapper.execute(KernelControllerContextAction.java:257) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.ExecutionWrapper.execute(ExecutionWrapper.java:47) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchExecutionWrapper(KernelControllerContextAction.java:125) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.KernelControllerContextAction.dispatchJoinPoint(KernelControllerContextAction.java:72) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.LifecycleAction.installActionInternal(LifecycleAction.java:202) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:54) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.dependency.InstallsAwareAction.installAction(InstallsAwareAction.java:42) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java:62) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:379) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:2044) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:1083) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.executeOrIncrementStateDirectly(AbstractController.java:1322) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1246) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1139) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:894) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:641) [jboss-dependency.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBean(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:319) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deployBeans(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:297) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.AbstractKernelDeployer.deploy(AbstractKernelDeployer.java:130) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.kernel.plugins.deployment.BasicKernelDeployer.deploy(BasicKernelDeployer.java:76) [jboss-kernel.jar:2.2.0.SP2]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.deployer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBasicXMLDeployer.java:92) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-mc.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.deployer.TempBasicXMLDeployer.deploy(TempBasicXMLDeployer.java:193) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-mc.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.server.AbstractMCServerBase.bootstrapMcAndDescriptors(AbstractMCServerBase.java:335) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-mc.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.mc.server.AbstractMCServerBase.doStart(AbstractMCServerBase.java:282) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-mc.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.as.server.AbstractJBossASServerBase.doStart(AbstractJBossASServerBase.java:381) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-as.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at org.jboss.bootstrap.impl.base.server.AbstractServer$StartServerTask.run(AbstractServer.java:413) [jboss-bootstrap-impl-base.jar:2.1.0-alpha-6]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [:1.7.0_261]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Could not create directory for root '/opt/shared/web/jboss/jboss-6.1.0.Final/server/default/tmp/vfs' (prefix 'automount', suffix '') after 10 attempts
    at org.jboss.vfs.TempFileProvider.createTempDir(TempFileProvider.java:115) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.TempFileProvider.create(TempFileProvider.java:73) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.util.automount.Automounter.getTempFileProvider(Automounter.java:228) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.util.automount.Automounter.access$700(Automounter.java:48) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.util.automount.Automounter$RegistryEntry.mount(Automounter.java:250) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.util.automount.Automounter$RegistryEntry.access$000(Automounter.java:232) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.util.automount.Automounter.mount(Automounter.java:117) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.vfs.util.automount.Automounter.mount(Automounter.java:90) [jboss-vfs.jar:3.0.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.classloading.spi.vfs.dependency.VFSClassLoaderPolicyModule.create(VFSClassLoaderPolicyModule.java:271) [jboss-classloading-vfs.jar:2.2.1.GA]
    ... 36 more
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: Hi, please give some more context such as what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far.